# How to get fisheye lens border in shot?

Tags: filming, lenses

I'm about to buy a camcorder with a 62mm diameter lens, and I'd like to get a fisheye with it.

I would like my shots to end up like shown [here](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-8bWDl7tss-o/VDZn_YybcmI/AAAAAAAACIc/Ssdyzc59KRw/s1600/Schermata%2B2014-10-09%2Balle%2B12.47.47.png), with a little bit of lens border in shot.

I can't seem to find an answer to this question online, does the lens diameter have to me smaller than my camera to achieve this or is it some kind of special lens?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer your question about the lenses, but any good editing software should let you apply a fisheye effect after the fact. Just find the effects menu in whatever software you are using, and such an effect should be in there. For example, if you are using Final Cut Pro, the effects menu should be in the top right hand corner ([here's the Apple help page about adding effect in Final Cut)](https://support.apple.com/guide/final-cut-pro/add-video-effects-ver4e33bc9/mac#:~:text=You%20add%20video%20effects%20to,Effects%20browser%2C%20select%20an%20effect.).

Answer (score 0):

The front element lens diameter does not affect the ability to create a fisheye effect. To get a true, in-camera fisheye, you need to use a [fisheye lens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisheye_lens).

A smaller lens diameter *might* be useful for creating in-camera vignetting (the rounded black borders but without the spherical distortion) if you stack enough filters or step up rings and use a wide enough focal length.

Beyond those two in-camera effects, you can create a fisheye effect in post, as described in another answer.